# x-requext-id header propagation in keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, istio, jaeger, ambassador

I am using keycloak to implement OAuth2 code authorization flow in a kubernetes cluster governed by an API gatware Ambassador, I am using Istio Service mesh to add all the tracability, mTLS features to my cluster. One of which is Jaeger which requires all the services to forward `x-request-id` header in order to link the spans into a specific trace.

When request is sent, Istio's proxy attached to ambassador will generate the x-request-id and forward the request keycloak for authorization, when the results are sent back to the ambassador, the header is dropped and therefore, the istio proxy of keycloak will be generating a new `x-header-id`. The following image shows the problem:

[image]

Here is a photo of the trace where I lost the x-request-id:

[image]

Is there a way I can force Keycloak to forward the `x-request-id` header if passed to it?

**Update**
here is the environment variables (ConfigMap) associated with Keycloak:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: keycloak-envars
data:
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: "admin"
  KC_PROXY: "edge"
  KC_DB: "postgres"
  KC_DB_USERNAME: "test"
  KC_DB_DATABASE: "keycloak"
  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems keycloak have the opentelemetry plugin that is disabled by default. Enabling it allows to send trace ids to Jaeger, you can enable it by setting `KC_OTEL` to True. For more information look into the [doc](https://www.keycloak.org/keycloak-benchmark/kubernetes-guide/latest/util/otel).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to restart your keycloak docker container with the environment variable `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`.

- ex: `docker run -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true jboss/keycloak`

Comment: it was actually enabled, still the headers aren't forwareded.